# HtmlAgilityPack - How to read certain table - c# 4.0

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

With using c# 4.0 and htmlagilitypack how can i read values inside certain table. I mean lets say there are 10 tables and i want to read values from 6 th or i have table id.

Or lets say i want to read td value coming after certain td.

Or table coming after certain div or element or text. Are these possible ?

Comment: What are you talking about? Show markup. Explain what you need to fetch.

Comment: What have you tried? A decent starter is here: http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/011211-1.aspx I'd read that, try the things you mentioned and if you can't get it, come back with more specific situations.

Comment: thanks for the link. for example there might be many tables in the page. lets say i want to get table after certain keyword or div element. How can i do that ? reading elements after certain markups.

Comment: Removed the (unnecessary) remark on the library's documentation.

Comment: Stop writing text and paste some example HTML into your question. With an example of what input you have and what output you expect, it's possible to help. Without it, it's impossible.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Everything you have asked about could be done relatively easily.  It doesn't matter that its documentation might be lacking, it should be similar to XML and the network's `XmlDocument` implementation in both use and functionality.

> How can I read values inside certain table?  Let's say there are 10 tables and I want to read values from 6th or I have table id.

Finding the 6th table:

```
// XPath
var table6 = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[6]");

// LINQ
var table6 = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("table").Skip(5).FirstOrDefault();
```

Finding the table/element by id:

```
var myTable = doc.GetElementById("myTable");

// XPath
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//table[@id='myTable']");
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//*[@id='myTable']");

// LINQ
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("table")
    .Where(table => table.Attributes.Contains("id"))
    .SingleOrDefault(table => table.Attributes["id"].Value == "myTable");
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants()
    .Where(e => e.Attributes.Contains("id"))
    .SingleOrDefault(e => e.Attributes["id"].Value == "myTable");
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants("table")
    .SingleOrDefault(table => table.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "myTable");
var myTable = doc.DocumentNode
    .Descendants()
    .SingleOrDefault(e => e.GetAttributeValue("id", null) == "myTable");
```

> Let's say I want to read td value coming after certain td.

```
// XPath
var certainTd = table6.SelectSingleNode("//td[2]");
var tdAfterCertainTd = certainTd.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::td[1]");

// LINQ (not so easy)
var certainTd = table6.Descendants("td").Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();
var tdAfterCertainTd = certainTd.NextSibling;
while (tdAfterCertainTd != null)
{
    if (tdAfterCertainTd.Name == "td")
        break;
    tdAfterCertainTd = tdAfterCertainTd.NextSibling;
}
```

> Table coming after certain div or element or text.

```
// XPath
var certainDiv = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[1]");
var tableAfterCertainDiv = certainDiv.SelectSingleNode("following-sibling::table[1]");

// LINQ (not so easy)
var certainDiv = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").FirstOrDefault();
var tableAfterCertainDiv = certainDiv.NextSibling;
while (tableAfterCertainDiv != null)
{
    if (tableAfterCertainDiv.Name == "table")
        break;
    tableAfterCertainDiv = tableAfterCertainDiv.NextSibling;
}
```

You should notice some patterns.

Comment: thanks great answer. are there any place where i can learn xpath. any good tutorial e book or video. thank you.

Comment: I don't know of any tutorial sites. I would just recommend finding one that lists operators, functions and syntax and try writing programs to work on some data. And do a lot.